# 360 degrees view for Account/Contact in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2016

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016, 360-degrees

I'm working on Ms Dynamics CRM 2016 and I'm looking for a tool or a way to have a 360° view on the Account/Contact forms. I want to insert ergonomic parts and graphics to the forms like the photo shows.
Thanks for help.

[image]

Comment: I'm puzzled: "ergonomic parts and graphics" such as ?

Comment: @Alex Thank you for helping. I edited the post to give an example

Comment: I see. That's actually a HTML Web Resource embedded in the form. MSDN as always has lots of info about how to build one.

Comment: I found nothing about that on the web

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps can be embedded in IFRAMEs, with a URL in the form of

> https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=YOUR_API_KEY&q=Eiffel+Tower,Paris+France
>
> The following URL parameter is required:
>
> **q**: defines the place to highlight on the map. It accepts a location as either a place name, address, or **place ID**. The string should be URL-escaped, so an address such as "City Hall, New York, NY" should be converted to City+Hall,New+York,NY. (The Google Maps Embed API supports both + and %20 when escaping spaces.) Place IDs should be prefixed with **place_id**:.

Comment: Bing most likely has this too (you'd be able to reuse the key from CRM itself) but I have no clue about it.

Comment: Thank you for your suggest. But unfortunately it's not what i'm looking for. I'm looking for tools to insert an ergonomic design and graphics to the Contact/Account form

Comment: I have no idea what that means, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Check Single View Builder for Dynamics CRM: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aAO8EGw-f_4

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately Single View Builder seems as a powerfull tool but not free.

Comment: I've also found the following solution: https://richux.codeplex.com/. I've never used it, however screens look promising :)

Comment: Thank you very much Piotr, this tool seems very interesting im going to try it.